# c# 2 byte calculation checksum

Tags: c#, checksum

I need help with a checksum calculation. 
This is (not my code!) but from specification
http://www.leupamed.at/?wpdmact=process&did=NC5ob3RsaW5r

```
private void CalcCheckSum(string msg, out byte checksum1, out byte checksum2)
{
byte cs1 = 0;
byte cs2 = 0;
// Always use "\n" as line break when calculating the checksum.
msg = msg.Replace("\r\n", "\n"); // Find and replace CR LF with LF
msg = msg.Replace("\r", "\n"); // Find and replace CR with LF.
for (int i = 0; i < msg.Length; i++)
{
cs1 += (byte) msg[i];
cs2 += cs1;
}
checksum1 = cs1;
checksum2 = cs2;
}
```

I must create a packet like this:

`<!--:Begin:Chksum:1:--><!--:Ack:Msg:3:0:--><!--:End:Chksum:1:184:62:-->`

The string `<!--:Ack:Msg:3:0:-->` is the actual data, I must calculate two checksum bytes (184 and 62) and insert these into the final packet (as seen above).

But my result from the calculation is 10 and 62

```
var msg = "<!--:Ack:Msg:3:0:-->";
byte checksum1 = 0;
byte checksum2 = 0;
CalcCheckSum(msg, out checksum1, out checksum2);
```

I don't now how to calculate correct checksum values.
This is checksum for response. Not for validating request.
I can't upload image due to low reputation, so look at last line in specification: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Gs9q9SJteadVRwSVc1a2FmUTg/edit?usp=sharing
This acknowledge message is independent on request. Only it must be response to request message ID 3.

**Solution?**

After calculating checksum:

checksum1 = 256 - (10 + 62) = 184

checksum2 = 62

Device communicating without problem, now.

Comment: Maybe you should explain that syntax, and tell us what is the exact problem. A sample input and output would help a lot.

Comment: CalcCheckSum is function which must calculate string in 2 bytes. <!--:Ack:Msg:3:0:--> is a calculated string but I can't take output bytes (cs1 = 184, cs2 = 62) as example in documentation.

Comment: I still don't get it.

Comment: In the example above, what is the expected value of `msg` and resultant `checksum1` and `checksum2` values?

Comment: So you're just trying to parse out the two values from that string?

Comment: Yes, two checksum values.

Comment: According to the documentation of the BM800, you aren't generating the values of the transferred checksum, you are generating the values to *validate* the checksum.  So, your values of 10 and 62 are correct.  According to the documentation, you must apply `checksum1 += transferredChecksum1; checksum2 += checksum1; checksum1 += transferredChecksum2; checksum2 += checksum1;` to validate the checksum.  Where checksum1 is 10, checksum2 is 62, transferredChecksum1 is 184 and transferredChecksum2 is 62. If checksum1 and checksum2 equal zero after that calculation, then the checksum is valid.

Comment: http://www.leupamed.at/?wpdmact=process&did=NC5ob3RsaW5r (pdf) - page 34

Comment: please update the question - dont reply in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calculating checksum:

checksum1 = 256 - (10 + 62) = 184

checksum2 = 62

Probably this question is too specific and no one has experience with this type of checksum calculation.
Device communicating without problem, now.